# Best practice for configuring flyway in production

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

We are planning to move our application in production which is using flyway with spring boot .Most of the them time we are facing Validate database  exception doing application start

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed: 
Migration checksum mismatch for migration version .
```

To recover from this exception we need to correct data on database or last option is reset database  .But when we move to production to fight with this exception it will be nightmare .So we want to follow best practice for configuring flyway in production .We need answer from expert who has been  using flyaway for several years in production .Thank You .

Answer (score 2):

- What is it?

The checksum validation from `Flyway` is basically a check between the checksum of the current migration file in your app against the checksum from the same migrtion it already run in the past. You can check this list on your database, under `flyway_schema_history` table created and used by Flyway.

- What it means?

It means that the script you app has when it starts is not the same Flyway already applied in the past and since it can't figure out if that is correct or not, it fails. Ideally, you should never change a script you already applied, you should always evolve and create new ones, that's the whole idea about migrations.

- How to avoid it?

As said before, you should never change scripts that were already executed before. You should always create new ones. Of course if that happens on a dev environment and you figure out changes are needed.

- Extra

I see in your error message it says `version .`, which means that probably you haven't defined a properly name for your migration script. By default, and as a good practice, names are in this format: `VyyyyMMd_HHmmss__action_you_performed_on_your_database` and all that will be translated to the Flyway table as `version` and `description`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience using flyway,

*Flyway* tries to compare the checksum of your `SQL script` with the checksum previously run. This exception usually happens if you edit an `SQL script` that has already been applied by *Flyway*, causing a discrepancy in the checksum.

**Development environment**, you can delete your database and start migrations again.

**Production environment**, you must never edit SQL scripts that have already been applied on ***Production environment***. Just create a few new SQL scripts in the future.